# How to write wxListBox entries into a .txt file in python

Tags: python, wxpython, wxformbuilder

I'm trying to program a wxFormBuilder interface to write text from a wxListBox into a text file. My current code:

```
def clickSave (self, parent):
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.SAVE)
    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        fn = dialog.GetPath() 
        fh = open(fn, "w")
        for i in range(self.m_listBox4.GetCount()):
            listBox = self.m_listBox4.GetString(i) + "\n"
        fh.write(listBox)
        fh.close()
```

Currently this code saves only the last entry in the listbox instead of all of the entries. I'm also having trouble importing lists from a text file into the wxListBox. With the code I have, I'm getting a "TypeError: String or Unicode type required" error:

```
def clickOpen(self, event):
    dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", "*.*", wx.OPEN)

    if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        stockinfo = []
        fn = dialog.GetPath()
        fh = open(fn, "r") 
        csv_fh = csv.reader(fh)
        for row in csv_fh:
            stockinfo.append(row)
        fh.close()
        for rows in stockinfo:
            self.m_listBox4.Append(rows)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the

```
for i in range(self.m_listBox4.GetCount()):
    listBox = self.m_listBox4.GetString(i) + "\n"
```

you always overwrite the content of listBox variable, therefore only the last row stays in. You probably wanted to do:

```
    listBox += self.m_listBox4.GetString(i) + "\n"
```

However, concatenating strings is very inefficient. You should be doing something like:

```
for i in range(self.m_listBox4.GetCount()):
    fh.write(self.m_listBox4.GetString(i))
    fh.write("\n")
```

As for the other one:

```
for row in csv_fh:
    stockinfo.append(row)
```

Here, row is not a String or Unicode, but a sequence. You are just putting this sequence into a list and trying to add it to the list box later. Change

```
   self.m_listBox4.Append(str(rows))
```

just to see what it does.

Comment: Hey Petr, your save function works perfectly, so thank you so much for that. <br> 

The open function does bring in the lists, but each line is surrounded by both brackets and quotations. So the uploaded list looks something like: <br>
["Line 1"]
["Line 2"]
["Line 3"]

While in the original text document it appears as:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3

Is there any way to use slicing to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, if you read with a csv reader, you receive tuples, then when you convert them to a string, you get ["something"], ... If you want just the strings, do not read with the csv.reader, just: for i in fh.readlines(): ... Also if you have no need to keep the data read, perform the list insertion in the same cycle as the reading.